# Misplaced diacritics with Graphite renderer and LuaLaTeX. Any

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

I am trying to typeset some Kashur (Kashmiri) text with a Graphite font, i.e., [Awami Nastaliq](https://software.sil.org/awami/download/). Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[%
  english,%
  bidi              = {bidi-r}%
]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\ksfnt[%
  IgnoreFontspecFile,%
  Extension         = {.ttf},%
  Renderer          = {Graphite}%
]{AwamiNastaliq-Regular}

\begin{document}
\ksfnt
یِہ (کوٗر) چھَےٚ اَم کھؠوَان۔
\end{document}
```

I need LuaLaTeX for `bidi` support, but unfortunately, the rendered diacritics aren't up to the mark:

[image: 1]

The correct output can be seen with LibreOffice:

[image: 2]

Is there any LuaLaTeX hack for fixing this?

I have [reported](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/276) this on GitHub too.

Comment: With your MWE, I get the diacritics placed as by Libre Office (though the parentheses are backward). Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Comment: @Thérèse It is up to date. TeX Live 2024 with all packages updated. Are you sure you have exactly copy-pasted the MWE? Because the parenthesis problem was occurring with `bidi=basic`, it doesn't occur with `bidi=bidi-r`.

Comment: I see! There is something wrong with the update in TeX Live 2024! I have an old output of this text (just without the parenthesized word) and it [has](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ3IP.png) the correct placement of diacritics. I think the hack won't be too difficult then.

Comment: @Thérèse Are you also using TeX Live 2024 or do you get the output on TeX Live 2023?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I can confirm for tl2024, with 2023 it is fine (in both cases I used the same luaotfload from dev). babel is not involved, it happens also if one sets the directions manually.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer which (changed) files are causing the issue then according to you?

Comment: I would suspect a problem in harfbuzz (or a bad interaction with harfbuzz). luahbtex in tl2023 uses harfbuzz 7.0.1, in tl2024 it is 8.3.0. @MarcelKrüger

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I’m using 2023, updated until a week or so ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this by passing `RawFeature = {script=arab}` to the font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  english,%
  bidi              = {bidi-r}%
]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\ksfnt[%
  IgnoreFontspecFile,%
  Extension         = {.ttf},%
  Renderer          = {Graphite},%
  RawFeature        = {script=arab}
]{AwamiNastaliq-Regular}

\begin{document}
\ksfnt
یِہ (کوٗر) چھَےٚ اَم کھؠوَان۔
\end{document}
```

The change comes from a HarfBuzz change which made Graphite mode more script dependent, so now you need to pass an (at least approximately) correct script to get correct shaping. sually you would do that with the `fontspec` option `Script = Arabic`, but `fontspec` doesn't forward that directly since the font does not contain Arabic specific features.

Comment: Okay, interestingly now the parentheses are printed incorrectly. Shifting back to `bidi=basic` helped. Maybe not now, but can the font or `fontspec` understand this without having to add `RawFeatures`? I don't mind putting a feature request on Awami too if something in the font needs to be changed. I am asking this as not everyone knows these subtleties and thus the font becomes lesser accessible to the general public.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/silnrsi/font-awami/issues/13

Comment: @Niranjan That `RawFeature=...` is needed instead of `Script = Arabic` is something which should be changed in (probably) fontspec. That the script needs to be specified at all is a more general thing which should be handled by `babel`. (That should already work as long as you use babel commands to select the font.) From luaotfload side we could change `script=auto` to handle Graphite fonts better (basically the way to say that luaotfload should figure out the script itself) but since hardly anyone uses that there is no big motivation to work on this.

Comment: Anyway the font does not have any real influence here.